# unable to receive sms in android using uthsms.net

Tags: android, sms

I was tried send free SMS using **uthsms.net**  in android program... but unable to receive sms any mobile number ..

I was using below code ,unable to get any exception or errors ....

I tried simulator and device  both of them not same problem, i was struggle this problem last  one weak

please give me anyone for good suggestion about uthsms.net

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.uthsms.net/index.php?on=sms-status");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "91"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sindh", "xxxxxxxxxxx"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gateway", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hyderabad", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remLen", "135"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recaptcha_challenge_field", "03AHJ_VuvO-0yifgUvXaYPdlTF5QBZwKQlo-gQE8FYioRNi3klTtM_MLDnbzuOH8uUFzX1LXVltrZy8kBcTDY176rLVu3M1EvbkF3fQKxQ3t3nBedlshOvNXHZDFCO5I4Sdm4AkIdpQViTRBDzB6pU9OIombEKY6yy7OsY1Faob6Z47pNAaKWqFGc"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recaptcha_response_field", "2485842 76"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", "126"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("y", "31"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("button", "Send SMS"));
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("http responce code"+statusLine);
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                 entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.e(null,"entity"+ entity.toString());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader =   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()), 65728);
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        System.out.println("finalResult " + sb.toString());
```